# Regarding popcorn time app

Tags: node.js

I am curious about how popcorn time works. I have read somewhere and it seems that the app is centered upon a group of APIs.
One for torrents, another for the movie info, and another for the poster, [as well as] an API for the subtitles making the end-product entirely automated with no hosting necessary. All Popcorn Time does is “take existing information and put it together.

How did they able to make everything entirely automated ?

Comment: While the answers may be fascinating, this seems like way too broad of a question for S.O.

Answer (score 1):

I download myself from theirs github what I think it is a good place to you start. https://github.com/popcorn-time/popcorn-app. Unfortunately their service depends from a service what was shut down recently. This code in the github just show the code of the client. So, if we want to create some similar service the chalenge now it is to create something close to the old Popcorn service, preferably 100% automated.

In my first look, I believe they used to merge all the information into a REST service http://subapi.com/. This may be found here https://github.com/popcorn-time/popcorn-app/blob/master/js/frontend/providers/torrents.js . this may be the service what was shut down. By the quality of the information this don't look like something 100% automated but humanly managed.

As the service is turned off it is not easy to see how was exactly this service works. Look to the client we can try to discovery some excepted JSONs. I have been trying to discovery to create a similar service based on the torrents informations on the web.

This is the best what I could do so far ( NOT WORKING VERSION ):

```
<?php  
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Content-type: text/json');  
?>{
"movies":[
    {
        "imdb_id":      "tt1234721",
        "title":        "Robocop",
        "year":         "2014",
        "runtime":      "118 minutes",
        "synopsis":     "In 2028 Detroit, when Alex Murphy - a loving husband, father and good cop - is critically injured in the line of duty, the multinational conglomerate OmniCorp sees their chance for a part-man, part-robot police officer",
        "voteAverage":  "6.7",
        "poster":       "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAyOTUzMTcxN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMjkyOTc1MDE@._V1_SX214_.jpg",
        "backdrop":     "http://coolandcollected.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/neca-robocop-2.jpg",
        "torrents":     [ {"1080P": ["http://torrage.com/torrent/6CCD91113CDE3D36A2B213BF701EB251A5E580C8.torrent"] } ],
        "torrent":      ["http://torrage.com/torrent/6CCD91113CDE3D36A2B213BF701EB251A5E580C8.torrent"],
        "videos":       [],
        "subtitles":    [],
        "seeders":      ["udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80",  "udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80", "udp://tracker.istole.it:6969", "udp://tracker.ccc.de:80", "udp://open.demonii.com:1337"],
        "leechers":     ["udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80",  "udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80", "udp://tracker.istole.it:6969", "udp://tracker.ccc.de:80", "udp://open.demonii.com:1337"]
    }
]
}'
```